# Getting a previous release from Git

Tags: git

When I go to https://github.com/zxing/zxing I find that the code I want is under 
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/c1df162b95e07928afbd4830798cc1408af1ac67/actionscript

I have forked and downloaded the master, but can't figure out what I am supposed to do to get this release.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

pretty easy done

```
git checkout c1df162b95e07928afbd4830798cc1408af1ac67
```

and you are on exactly that revision, while

```
git checkout master
```

brings you back to the master branch

Answer (score 1):

You can use git checkout to get the release.

The git checkout command lets you navigate between the branches created by git branch. Checking out a branch updates the files in the working directory to match the version stored in that branch, and it tells Git to record all new commits on that branch. Think of it as a way to select which line of development you’re working on.

So, let's use your git address to do it:

```
git checkout address
```

Which, in this case, would be:

```
git checkout c1df162b95e07928afbd4830798cc1408af1ac67
```

Using git checkout is a breeze, and if you ever want to get back to master, you can just use git checkout again.

```
git checkout master
```